# Jquery - FadeIn() Effect not working in script loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When the user .mouseenters the .container i would like the link to fadeIn, and when the user .mouseleaves the .container i would like the link to fadeOut. So far this is working. How can i slow down the transition? Using 5000-10000 seems to be too fast still.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.container').mouseenter(function(){
        // When mouse enters the .container, #facial slides to center of .container.
        $('#facial').animate({right: '25%'})
        // After #facial slides to center it delays for 500ms.      
                    .delay(500)
        // After #facial delays it expands it's width to 100% of .container.
                    .animate({right: 0, width: '100%'});
        // show the span link at bottom as a H2 with center aligned.
        $('span').fadeIn('slow');
    }); 


    $('.container').mouseleave(function(){
       // Mouse leaves .container, and span fades out slowly.
       $('span').css('display','none'); 
       $('span').fadeOut('slow');
       // Mouse leaves the .container, #facial shrinks it's width to 50%.
       // #facial slides back to right of .container.
       $('#facial').animate({right: 0, width: '50%'});

   }); 
});
```

[Here is my Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dshojaei/sy4pv8z3/48/)

Comment: Ok... so it seems right after i posted this i messed with my code. I changed the faceIn() to 'slow', and it fixed the loop. Does anybody know how i can slow down the transition? It seems to be too fast for me, and when i try to change to 5000 it's too fast still.

Comment: try this : https://jsfiddle.net/sy4pv8z3/51/

Answer (score 0):

the code works but is slow for display span

```
$('span').fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue (at least in JSfiddle code) is with:

```
display: none;
```

Try setting display to block and opacity to 0.
This is a styling pitfall many people encounter as items switching display during animations will suddenly pop out without those set animations. I believe this is the effect that you are looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/sy4pv8z3/52/

Note: The time in fadeIn & fadeOut functions are in ms (milliseconds). You should be able to achieve a nice transition with 500ms and less.